# shuffle array values randomly

Tags: php, arrays, random, element

How can I reorder the array entries with a random logic?
for example :

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
```

change to :

```
$new_arr = array('five', 'one', 'three', 'four', 'two');
```

Comment: Google, words: "php array random", results: way too many. Don't be lazy. Also, word is "random", not "randomistically", that word doesn't even exist (but I like it nevertheless).

Comment: If you want to write your own method look at the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in `shuffle()` PHP function:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
    shuffle($arr);
    print_r($arr);
?>
```